# Which machines are trying to connect to my Solaris machine via SSH?

Tags: ssh, solaris

I have a Solaris machine ( Solaris 10 )

Is it possible to see from my machine ( logs ) which machines are try to connect to my machine by SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Solaris 10 system I have to hand ssh connections (and other auth related information) are logged to

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

e.g.

```
Oct 10 15:15:46 solbase sshd[1481]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted publickey for iain from 192.168.254.188 port 52197 ssh2
```

is a connection by me to a Solaris 10 machine and

```
Oct 10 15:17:33 solbase sshd[1481]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Received disconnect from 192.168.254.188: 11: disconnected by user
```

is a disconnect from the same machine.

Comment: Lucky Iain, not being stuck in the late '90s like me!  Upvote for you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Assuming your logs are set up reasonably standardly (and that Sun hasn't been varying things gratuitously), you should see something much like these logs, which are from `/var/log/secure` on a Solaris 8 box that I have handy:

A successful login (using a public key rather than a password):

```
Oct 10 15:09:15 xxxx sshd[22706]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted publickey for myuser from 192.168.1.87 port 56035 ssh2
```

A failed attempt:

```
Oct 10 15:09:27 xxxx sshd[22726]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Illegal user fred from 192.168.1.87
Oct 10 15:09:27 xxxx sshd[22726]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Failed none for illegal user fred from 192.168.1.87 port 56036 ssh2
Oct 10 15:09:28 xxxx sshd[22726]: [ID 800047 auth.error] error: Could not get shadow information for NOUSER
Oct 10 15:09:28 xxxx sshd[22726]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Failed password for illegal user fred from 192.168.1.87 port 56036 ssh2
```